# Get an certain block of bytes from a file

Tags: c++

For an assignment i have to send a file through xml by coding it with base64. 
I have to send the file in multiple parts. For that i want to get a block of bytes from that file.
I hoped that i could do that with a blocksize and blocknumber parameter.

But im not always getting bytes back, i gues im doing something wrong or just missed something stupid.

I created the following code:

```
// int blocknumber (the blocknumber thats requested)
// int blocksize (by default we want to use 1024)

//Content of the block
ifstream is;
is.open(fullPath.c_str(), ios::binary);

// get length of file:
is.seekg(0, ios::end);
int length = is.tellg();

char* buffer = new char [blocksize];
//test if file is bigger then size
if (length >= blocknumber * blocksize) {
    //skip to relevent part
    is.seekg(blocknumber * blocksize, ios::beg);
    is.read(buffer, blocksize);
}
```

This is a result that i get when i get data back

```
blocknumber 0
GkXfo6NChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKIbWF0cm9za2FCh4ECQoWBAhhTgGcB
```

But with blocknumber 3 i get nothing.

Comment: What is `blocksize` and `lenght`?

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. Seeks can fail. Reads can fail.

Comment: blocksize is the size of the block that i want to get from the file.

its also used to calculate how many blocks the has. ( filesize / blocksize)

length = An integral value of type streampos with the number of characters between the beginning of the input sequence and the current position.

meaning from beginning to end. (full file size)

Answer (score 0):

Its solved.... It was very very stupid indeed...

THe problem wasnt the code after all but the encoding part after it.

Block size 512
Block 5
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

This will proberly leave the biggest facepalm mark in history.

Thanks for the support